# Bug in numpy.shape()?

Tags: python, numpy

I am playing with day 10 of the [2019 advent of code challenge](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/10) and found `np.shape()` behaving weirdly right at the start:

```
In [45]:
import numpy as np
file = open('Day10.data')
astermap = file.read()
print(astermap)
Out [46]:
##.##..#.####...#.#.####
##.###..##.#######..##..
..######.###.#.##.######
.#######.####.##.#.###.#
[..total of 25 lines]

# astermap is a str, which I make a list of lists

In [46]:
astermap = astermap.split('\n')
astermap = list(map(list, astermap))
Here I found some strange behavior for numpy.shape: the shape should be (25,24)

In [48]:
np.shape(astermap)
Out[48]:
(25,)

In [49]:
np.shape(astermap[0])
Out[49]:
(24,)

In [51]:
type(astermap)
Out[51]:
list

In [52]:
type(astermap[0])
Out[52]:
list
```

When I run the same code with a smaller example `astermap = '.#..#\n.....\n#####\n....#\n...##'`, it works as expected and `np.shape(astermap)` returns `(5, 5)`. So I strongly expect that the reason must lie in the format of the str after reading the file. However, I can't see a difference of types between the str I import and the str I create by hand.

Can somebody explain?

Comment: Trailing newline.

Comment: Print the list of lists before you turn it into an array

Comment: `astermap` is a list of lists.  If `arr = np.array(astrmap)` has shape (25,), it means the dtype is object, and it contains lists.  One or more of those lists has a different length (not 24).  Identify which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you convert a list of lists into a numpy array, it only makes it all a numpy array if the inner lists are of the same length. Otherwise, it makes an array of python lists.

Example:

Running `np.array(list(map(list,(" asdf fdsa".split()))))` returns:

```
array([['a', 's', 'd', 'f'],
       ['f', 'd', 's', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

Which has shape (2,4). But `np.array(list(map(list,(" asdf fdsafda".split()))))` returns:

```py
array([list(['a', 's', 'd', 'f']),
       list(['f', 'd', 's', 'a', 'f', 'd', 'a'])], dtype=object)
```

Which has shape (2,).

Even if you convert the inner list to numpy arrays, they still won't display when taking `np.shape()`, because they're not all the same length.

I'd assume it's very likely one of your lists is a different length, which could be due to splitting by new lines `'/n'`. It's possible one of your line values is an empty string `['']`.